# MySQL get count for each returned item

Tags: mysql

Currently having a little issue is accumulation of a query i am trying to run.

I currently have the following SQL

```
SELECT a.productId
     , b.name 
  FROM `pk-product-service`.bookingProduct a
  join `pk-product-service`.product b 
    on a.productId = b.productId
 group 
    by a.productId
```

which currently returns

```
| productId |  name  | 
| 1         | Apple  |
| 2         | Banana |
| 3         | Pear   |
| 4         | Grapes |
```

I currently want to get the count of each of those productIds. i.e., productId 1 Apple has a count of 5 in the product table, productId 2 Banana has a count of 3 etc.

Ultimately i want my table to populate like the following:

```
| productId |  name  | count |
| 1         | Apple  | 5     |
| 2         | Banana | 3     |
| 3         | Pear   | 1     |
| 4         | Grapes | 0     |
```

but i am unsure how this can be archieved.

Comment: FWIW, I think allowing the inclusion of '-' in table/column identifiers is recklessly dangerous

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - use `count()` aggregation

```
SELECT  a.productId,b.name,count(*)
FROM `pk-product-service`.bookingProduct a
join `pk-product-service`.product b on a.productId = b.productId
group by a.productId,b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed in your code b.name in group by.
your code should be:

```
SELECT  a.productId,b.name,count(*)
FROM `pk-product-service`.bookingProduct a
join `pk-product-service`.product b on a.productId = b.productId
group by a.productId,b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `COUNT` *with* a left join, and join from the `product` table to the `bookingProduct` table.

```
SELECT
    p.productId,
    p.name,
    COUNT(bp.productId) AS count
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN bookingProduct bp
    ON p.productId = bp.productId
GROUP BY
    p.productId;
```

The logic here is that you want every product to appear in the result set, even if it has a zero count.  Using a left join is one way to accomplish this.  Note that my answer assumes that `product.productId` is a primary key or other unique column in that table, in which case we may select any other column besides `productId` while doing `GROUP BY`.  If not, then we would have to add `product.name` to the `GROUP BY` clause.